# How to add an unknown amount of dots to a line depending on length of word?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having trouble figuring out how to do the following in CSS/HTML:

```
Word 1.................................$45
Long Word 2............................$45
Long Word even longer..................$45
small..................................$45
```

I can't define how many dots there are for each word, because what the individual enters is dynamic.  How can I make it so that there are the right amount of dots?

**Edit:** I am not using a monospace font

Comment: Did you try subtracting the user input length from the maximum length?

Comment: Keep note, this only work if you are using a monospaced font

Comment: i'm not using a monospace font

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about a list:

```
<dl>
    <dt><span>Word 1</span></dt>
    <dd>$45</dd>

    <dt><span>Long Word 2</span></dt>
    <dd>$45</dd>

    <dt><span>ong Word even longer</span></dt>
    <dd>$45</dd>
</dl>
```

and then some CSS using pseudo classes and a few floats

```
dl { width: 500px }
dt { float: left; width: 400px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap }
dd { float: left; width: 100px; overflow: hidden }

dt span:after { content: " ....................................................................................................." }
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/P2fbz/)

There are many other ways to do this as well, the point is to add a lot of dots to an element that has no overflow and adjusts to cover the space between the first text and the second (the price).

Answer (score 0):

@adeneo's answer is near perfection, but 'Long Word' maybe longer.

Based on @adeneo's answer, i approved it as below:

```
<dl>
  <dt><span>Word 1</span></dt>
  <dd>$45</dd>

  <dt><span>Long Word 2</span></dt>
  <dd>$45</dd>

  <dt>
    <span>
      long Word even longer, 
      long Word even longer, 
      long Word even longer
    </span>
  </dt>
  <dd>$45</dd>
</dl>
```

and then some CSS using pseudo classes and a few floats:

```
dl { width: 500px }
dt { float: left; width: 400px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap }
dd { float: left; width: 100px; overflow: hidden }
dt span {max-width: 200px; overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;text-overflow:ellipsis; display: inline-block;}
dt:after { content: "...............................
......................................................................" }
```